# Mongo $group too slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, average

I have a mongo db collections of about 168,200,000 documents. I am trying to get the average of a certain field with $group, and I am using $match before the $group in the pipeline to use the index on client.city. But the query is taking about 5 minutes to run, which is very slow.

Here are the things I tried:

```
db.ar12.aggregate(
    {$match:{'client.city':'New York'}},
    {'$group':{'_id':'client.city', 'avg':{'$avg':'$length'}}}
)

db.ar12.aggregate(
    {$match:{'client.city':'New York'}},
    {'$group':{'_id':null, 'avg':{'$avg':'$length'}}}
)

db.ar12.aggregate(
    {$match:{'client.city':'New York'}}, 
    {$project: {'length':1}},
    {'$group':{'_id':null, 'avg':{'$avg':'$length'}}}
)
```

All 3 queries take about the same time, number of documents with client.city = to New York is 1,231,672, `find({'client.city':'New York').count()` takes a second to run

```
> db.version()
  3.2.0
```

**EDIT**

Here's the explain result... As for the comment for adding a compound index with length, would that help, although I am not search by length I want all lengthes...

```
{
"waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
"stages" : [
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "query" : {
                "client.city" : "New York"
            },
            "fields" : {
                "length" : 1,
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "clients.ar12",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                    "client.city" : {
                        "$eq" : "New York"
                    }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "client.city" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "client.city_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "client.city" : [
                                "[\"New York\", \"New York\"]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "length" : true
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "$const" : null
            },
            "total" : {
                "$avg" : "$length"
            }
        }
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have added a compound index of client.city and length, but to no avail the speed is still too slow, I tried these 2 queries:

```
db.ar12.aggregate(
    {$match: {'client.city':'New York'}}, 
    {$project: {'client.city':1, 'length':1}},
    {'$group':{'_id':'$client.city', 'avg':{'$avg':'$length'}}}
)
```

The above query wasn't using the compound index, so I tried this to force using it, and still nothing changed:

```
db.ar12.aggregate(
    {$match: { $and : [{'client.city':'New York'}, {'length':{'$gt':0}}]}}, 
    {$project: {'client.city':1, 'length':1}},
    {'$group':{'_id':'$client.city', 'avg':{'$avg':'$length'}}}
)
```

below is the explain of the last query:

```
{
"waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
"stages" : [
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "query" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "client.city" : "New York"
                    },
                    {
                        "length" : {
                            "$gt" : 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "fields" : {
                "client.city" : 1,
                "length" : 1,
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "clients.ar12",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "client.city" : {
                                "$eq" : "New York"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "length" : {
                                "$gt" : 0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "CACHED_PLAN",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "client.city" : 1,
                                "length" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "client.city_1_length_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "client.city" : [
                                    "[\"New York\", \"New York\"]"
                                ],
                                "length" : [
                                    "(0.0, inf.0]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "client" : {
                "city" : true
            },
            "length" : true
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$client.city",
            "avg" : {
                "$avg" : "$length"
            }
        }
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: can you run an explain and verify if the index is actually being used? see here for info on the aggregation explain option: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation

Comment: You may also want to look at having a compound index on client.city and length

Comment: Thanks @AdamComerford I added the result of the explain... I looked before and saw it is using my Index... Do you think the compound index would help?

Comment: If you add the compound index and project the _id out of the results you may get a covered index query and not touch the data at all

Comment: hmmmm will try now... index takes some time to be created. Will update when I know anything. thanks @AdamComerford

Comment: @AdamComerford please check the update, the new compound index didn't seem to help.

Comment: try making indexes. so that the next search will be too fast.

Comment: Can you provide the explain for the query you ran ?

Comment: @admix added the explain

Comment: try adding `_id: 0` to the projection stage (otherwise you can't satisfy the query with just the index) - notice the `_id` still listed as a field in the explain

Comment: There should be another explain that shows you how many records scanned and which index was used and how much time spent.
db.collection.explain.aggregate() - try this

Comment: @admix, `.explain.aggregate` doesn't work, aggregate([pipeline], {explain:true}) works and gives the result I showed you.

@AdamComerford unprojecting `_id` didn't help

Comment: db.collection.explain().aggregate(....) - sorry :)

Comment: @admix, I learned something new :), but it gives the same output :(

Comment: Did you remove the other explain? Double check if the result has: nscanned, nscannedObjects, millis

Comment: Also, on what fields you have indexes ?

Comment: @admix yes I removed the other explain, I reran the command, there isn't any nscanned or nscannedObjects... I have an index on client.city alone and another compound index on client.city and length

Comment: Which version of mongo you using ?

Comment: > db.version()
3.2.0

Comment: Do this: db.collection.explain("executionStats").aggregate(...) - will give info on how the query ran.

Comment: nope... gives out the same result

Comment: Can you try differenr modes: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#explain-method-executionstats

Comment: @admix tried all 3 and all 3 return the same result. Tried to change the city too from new york to something else but to no avail, still the explain returns the same output all the time

Comment: any success? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around, length goes from 1 till 70. So what I did is in python I iterated from 1 to 70, and found the count of each length for each city,

```
db.ar12.find({'client.city':'New York', 'length':i}).count()
```

which is very fast, then calculated the average in python, it is taking about 2 seconds to run.

This is not the best solution, since I have other queries to run, I don't know if I can find a work around for all of them...